# How to run sqlite command after python execution

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a twitter like app with a Python/Django backend as an API with Sqlite for a database. My question is how do I run an 'Inner Join' command within a class. Is it possible for a request to simply return a joint table and not have to necessarily create it in the database?

I have a separate table for Users,Tweets, and followed/follower so when trying to make a call for data I'm making multiple HTTP requests to get info from each table.

```
SELECT a.id AS profile_id , a.first_name, a.last_name, a.username, b.tweet_text, 
         b.created_on, b.author_id AS profile_id, c.follower_id AS profile_id, c.followed_id
FROM authapi_user a
INNER JOIN authapi_tweet b
ON a.id=b.author_id
INNER JOIN authapi_follower c
ON a.id=c.follower_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Go by this example for executing raw SQL queries in django

```py
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = {[self.baz]}")
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = {[self.baz]}")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```